# changing font family acording to the user language

Tags: flutter, localization

i need to change the application font family, according to user the language.

**The code is:**

```
 localizationsDelegates: const [
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: const [
            Locale('en', ''),
            Locale('ar', ''),
          ],
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you change language in interface? Or just the simple way: every script (so Latin and Arabic) with own font?

Comment: if the user's device language is Arabic, i need to make the ui use an specific font family.
else just using another font family. @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: So Latin text should be displayed with two different fonts (families) according language?

Comment: yes, or do that inside the theme. @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: You can use CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang

Comment: i am using flutter @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: Yes, and flutter uses also CSS (it may be slightly hidden, but nobody creates are totally new frameworks not compatible with web technologies)